# Как реализовать это в Bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно реализовать расположение двух элементов как на скриншоте
при этом желательно чтобы они были в одном row. Логотип всегда должен быть по центру, а кнопка всегда по правой стороне.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Без использование bootstrap.**
Используем абсолютное позиционирование, внутри `relative` контейнера.

```css
.foot {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.inner {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foot">
  <div class="center">
 <div class="inner">центр</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">право</div>
</div>
```

**Вариант на bootstrap**

```css
.centr {
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
}

.nomargings {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row nomargings">
  <div class="offset-2 col-8">
    <div class="centr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```